# Rails 3.2 - jQuery-UI images are not displayed on production mode

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My `applications.css` looks like:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require twitter/bootstrap
 *= require jquery_ui/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom
 *= require_tree .
```

And the jQuery-UI images are placed in `vendor/assets/stylesheets/jquery_ui/images`.

This setup works me well on my localhost (development mode), but when I push my app to heroku, the images from **jQuery-UI** are not displayed and I am getting errors like

> http://my-url.com/assets/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png

Is there something yet, what I have to allow for correct loading images from this folder with images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the images in the images directory instead. But maybe you should try to use the [jquery-ui-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-ui-rails) gem that already does this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tii, the **jquery-ui-rails** gem I'll surely try, but what's for me not so sure is the behavior on the production mode - because the images in development mode everything's working well but in production not...

Comment: Im not sure the assets precompile stuff will include images that are located in the stylesheets directory. Have you looked in your public stylesheets directory in production if there is any images there?